# What is the most queens that have been on the board in a grandmaster game?

Tags: grandmaster, records, pawn-promotion, queens, famous-games

There are quite a few grandmaster games with 3 queens or 4 queens, but what is the highest number of queens on the board in a game between two GMs?

I'd be interested in both the most on the board at the same time and the most total during the game.

Answer (score 13):

This sounds like a job for [Tim Krabbé](http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records/records.htm#Most%20queens), who presents two games with six queens: Szalanczy - Nguyen, Budapest 2009 and Anton - Franco, XXI Elgoibar Magistral 2011. I don't know how many of the participants were grandmasters.

There are some other games with 5+ queens at [Chess Siberia](http://www.chessib.com/five-six-queens-chess-games.html). Of these, [Miton - Benjamin](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1667656), World Open Philadelphia 2005 definitely features two grandmasters.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a PGN file of chess games you can use [CQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20140130143815/http://www.rbnn.com/cql/) to search it. Something like:

```
(match
  :pgn src.pgn
  :output queens.pgn
  (position
    :piececount [Qq] 3 8))
```

Should return all games with positions containing 3 to 8 Queens on the board.

**Edit:** The Aquarium interface from chessok has a CQL search capability and can read ChessBase databases, so I was able to search my reference database (5M+ games) to games with 5 or more queens. There were no GM games with more than 5 queens on the board. The Anton Guijarro - Franco game mentioned by dfan, is a GM (Anton) vs an IM (Franco). In addition to the Miton - Benjamin game mentioned by dfan, I found a game played about a month later, Hickl - Sokolov that had 5 queens.

Miton - Benjamin:

```
[Event "World op 33rd Philadelphia  6/??/2005"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2005.07.03"]
[Round "7"]
[White "Miton Kamil"]
[Black "Benjamin Joel"]
[Result "1-0"]
[Annotator ""]
[BlackElo "2563"]
[ECO "E33"]
[GameNo "3367517"]
[Source "ChessBase 11/10/1998"]
[WhiteElo "2592"]
[FEN ""]

1. d4 Nf6 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. c4 e6 4. Nc3 Bb4 5. Qd3 d6 6. a3 Bxc3+ 7. Qxc3 O-O 8.
e3 a5 9. Be2 Re8 10. b3 e5 11. d5 Ne7 12. Nd2 Bf5 13. O-O c6 14. dxc6 Nxc6 15.
Rd1 Rc8 16. Qb2 Qe7 17. Nb1 b5 18. Nc3 bxc4 19. bxc4 Ne4 20. Nb5 Red8 21. f3
Nc5 22. e4 Be6 23. Be3 Rb8 24. Qc3 a4 25. Rac1 Nb3 26. Rc2 h6 27. f4 f6 28.
Qe1 Bf7 29. Qf2 exf4 30. Qxf4 Ne5 31. Nc3 Nc5 32. Nd5 Bxd5 33. cxd5 Rb3 34.
Bxc5 dxc5 35. Bc4 Nxc4 36. Rxc4 Rxa3 37. d6 Qe6 38. Rxc5 Rb3 39. Ra5 a3 40.
Ra7 Rd7 41. Rxd7 Qxd7 42. e5 Rb2 43. Qc4+ Kh7 44. e6 Qa7+ 45. Qd4 Qb7 46. Qd3+
g6 47. Qf1 a2 48. e7 Rb1 49. e8=Q a1=Q 50. d7 Qb6+ 51. Kh1 Rxd1 52. Qe7+ Kg8
53. d8=Q+ Qxd8 54. Qxd8+ Rxd8 55. Qxa1 Rc8 56. h4 Rd8 57. Qa2+ Kg7 58. Kg1 Rd7
59. Kf2 Re7 60. Kf3 Rf7 61. Qa8 Re7 62. Qd8 Re5 63. Qd7+ Kf8 64. Qh7 Re6 65.
Qh8+ Kf7 66. Qc8 Ke7 67. Qh8 g5 68. Qh7+ Kd6 69. Qg7 Ke5 70. Qxh6 Rd6 71. Qh7
Re6 72. Qh5 1-0
```

Hickl - Sokolov:

```
[Event "Mainz Ordix op Mainz  8/13/2005"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2005.08.14"]
[Round "7"]
[White "Hickl Joerg"]
[Black "Sokolov Ivan"]
[Result "1-0"]
[Annotator ""]
[BlackElo "2691"]
[ECO "A07"]
[GameNo "3404712"]
[Source "ChessBase 11/10/1998"]
[WhiteElo "2537"]
[FEN ""]

1. g3 d5 2. Nf3 c6 3. Bg2 Bg4 4. b3 Nd7 5. Bb2 Bxf3 6. Bxf3 e5 7. d3 Ngf6 8.
O-O h5 9. c4 d4 10. Re1 Bc5 11. Na3 Bb4 12. Rf1 Nf8 13. Nc2 Be7 14. e3 Ne6 15.
exd4 exd4 16. Re1 Qd7 17. Qd2 h4 18. Rad1 Rd8 19. b4 Kf8 20. Re2 c5 21. bxc5
Bxc5 22. Nb4 hxg3 23. hxg3 Nc7 24. Rde1 a5 25. Nc2 b6 26. Ba3 Ne6 27. Re5 g6
28. Rxe6 fxe6 29. Bxc5+ bxc5 30. Qxa5 Rc8 31. Na3 Kg7 32. Re5 Qe7 33. Nb5 Nd7
34. Re2 Qg5 35. Qe1 e5 36. Nd6 Rb8 37. Bg2 Rb6 38. Nb5 Ra6 39. Rb2 Rb8 40. Bh3
Nf6 41. Re2 e4 42. dxe4 Nh5 43. Bg2 Rab6 44. e5 d3 45. Rd2 Rxb5 46. cxb5 c4
47. e6 Rd8 48. Rd1 d2 49. Qe4 c3 50. b6 Qf5 51. e7 c2 52. Rf1 d1=Q 53. exd8=Q
Qxd8 54. Qb4 Qd1 55. b7 c1=Q 56. b8=Q Qxf1+ 57. Bxf1 Nf6 58. Q4f8+ 1-0
```

Anton Guijarro - Franco:

```
[Event "XXI Elgoibar Magistral Elgoibar ESP 12/14/2011"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2011.12.18"]
[Round "6.4"]
[White "Anton Guijarro D"]
[Black "Franco Alonso A"]
[Result "1-0"]
[Annotator ""]
[BlackElo "2454"]
[ECO "A17"]
[GameNo "4719077"]
[Source "ChessBase 11/10/1998"]
[WhiteElo "2469"]
[FEN ""]

1. Nf3 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 b6 4. g3 Bb7 5. Bg2 Be7 6. O-O O-O 7. Re1 Ne4 8.
Nxe4 Bxe4 9. d3 Bb7 10. e4 c5 11. d4 cxd4 12. Nxd4 Nc6 13. Bf4 Nxd4 14. Qxd4
Bc5 15. Qd2 Qe7 16. a3 e5 17. Be3 a5 18. Rad1 Bc6 19. Bh3 Ra7 20. Bg5 f6 21.
Be3 a4 22. Bf1 Qe6 23. Qd3 Rc8 24. h4 Rac7 25. Kh2 Qe7 26. Rd2 Bxe3 27. Qxe3
Qc5 28. Qf3 Rf8 29. Qg4 Rcc8 30. h5 Rce8 31. Re3 Re6 32. Qd1 Re7 33. Bh3 Rff7
34. Bf5 Qxc4 35. Rc3 Qb5 36. Kg2 Rf8 37. Qg4 Kh8 38. Rcd3 Qc4 39. Rd6 Bb5 40.
Bxd7 Qf1+ 41. Kh2 Bxd7 42. Rxd7 Rxd7 43. Qxd7 h6 44. Qe7 Rg8 45. Qd6 Qe1 46.
Qb4 b5 47. Kg2 Kh7 48. Rd5 Qe2 49. Rd7 Rc8 50. Rxg7+ Kxg7 51. Qe7+ Kg8 52.
Qe6+ Kg7 53. Qd7+ Kf8 54. Qxc8+ Ke7 55. Qf5 Qxb2 56. Qh7+ Ke6 57. Qxh6 b4 58.
Qg6 bxa3 59. h6 a2 60. h7 a1=Q 61. Qf5+ Kd6 62. h8=Q Kc5 63. Qf8+ Kc4 64. Qe6+
Kd3 65. Qfxf6 Qd4 66. Qf3+ Kd2 67. Qh6+ Kc2 68. Qc6+ Kb1 69. g4 Qab2 70. g5 a3
71. g6 a2 72. g7 a1=Q 73. g8=Q Qaa3 74. Qgg3 Qxf3+ 75. Qxf3 Qc2 76. Qb5+ Qcb2
77. Qfd3+ Qxd3 78. Qxd3+ Kc1 79. Kf3 Qd4 80. Qe2 Qd6 81. Qc4+ Kd2 82. Qd5+ 1-0
```

Comment: Hickl-Sokolov is fascinating. I wonder if 55...Nxg3!? would have saved Black.

Answer (score 0):

Using the more recent version of [CQL](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql), this is even simpler:

```
// Chess Q 12704
// find positions with many queens

cql(input Mega_Database_2022.pgn)

sort #[Qq] >= 5
```

Finds all games that have 5 or more queens on the board and sorts them by the amount found. A total of 49 games were returned when I ran the script against Mega Database 2022. 22 (!) of these were online, played in 2020-2021. Some were pretty ridiculous (with 7 queens on the board!). Here are some interesting ones between IMs/GMs:

1. [Postny Evgeny](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/2804344) vs. [Gordievsky, Dmitry](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/24112798) at the 12th PNWCC Online blitz JP (2020):

   ```
   [FEN ""]
   [Event "PNWCC Online blitz JP 12th"]
   [Site "Lichess.org INT"]
   [Date "2020.06.06"]
   [Round "11"]
   [White "Postny, Evgeny"]
   [Black "Gordievsky, Dmitry"]
   [Result "1-0"]
   [ECO "C67"]
   [WhiteElo "2600"]
   [BlackElo "2559"]
   [StartPly "90"]

   1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 Nf6 4. O-O Nxe4 5. d4 Nd6 6. Bxc6 dxc6
   7. dxe5 Nf5 8. Qxd8+ Kxd8 9. Nc3 Be7 10. h3 Nh4 11. Nd4 Nf5
   12. Nde2 h5 13. Ne4 h4 14. Bg5 Bxg5 15. Nxg5 Ke7 16. Nf4 Rh6
   17. Rad1 a5 18. Rd2 Bd7 19. Nxf7 Rh7 20. Ng5 Rh6 21. Rfd1 Be8
   22. a4 Rc8 23. b3 c5 24. Rd3 c4 25. Nd5+ Kf8 26. Rf3 g6 27. Nxc7 Bc6
   28. Rf4 Ke7 29. Nd5+ Bxd5 30. Rxd5 c3 31. Rxa5 Rhh8 32. Rb5 Rc7
   33. Nf3 Rd8 34. Nxh4 Rd2 35. Nxg6+ Ke6 36. Nf8+ Ke7 37. Rxf5 Rxc2
   38. Ng6+ Ke8 39. Rf8+ Kd7 40. Rf7+ Kc8 41. Rxc7+ Kxc7 42. Rc5+ Kb6
   43. Rc4 Rc1+ 44. Kh2 c2 45. e6 Ka5 46. e7 b6 47. e8=Q Rh1+ 48. Kxh1 c1=Q+
   49. Rxc1 Kb4 50. Qb5+ Ka3 51. Qxb6 Kb2 52. Rc4 Ka1 53. Rc2 Kb1 54. Re2 Ka1
   55. Nf4 Kb1 56. h4 Ka1 57. h5 Kb1 58. h6 Kc1 59. h7 Kb1 60. h8=Q Kc1
   61. g3 Kb1 62. g4 Kc1 63. Qh2 Kb1 64. g5 Kc1 65. g6 Kb1 66. g7 Kc1
   67. g8=Q Kb1 68. a5 Kc1 69. a6 Kb1 70. a7 Kc1 71. a8=Q Kb1 72. Qbb8 Kc1
   73. b4 Kd1 74. b5 Kc1 75. b6 Kd1 76. Qbf8 Kc1 77. b7 Kd1 78. b8=Q Kc1
   79. Qfe8 Kd1 80. Ng2 Kc1 81. f4 Kd1 82. f5 Kc1 83. f6 Kd1 84. f7 Kc1
   85. f8=Q Kd1 86. Qhh8 Kc1 87. Kh2 Kd1 88. Kh3 Kc1 89. Kh4 Kd1 90. Kg5 Kc1
   91. Kf6 Kd1 92. Ke7 Kc1 93. Kd8 Kd1 94. Nf4 Kc1 95. Ng6 Kd1 96. Qh5 Kc1
   97. Ne7 Kd1 98. Nc8 Kc1 99. Qhh8 Kd1 100. Rh2 Kc1 101. Qh1# 1-0
   ```
2. Synchev, Klemetry vs. [Shahade, Gregory P](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/2009064) at a Titled Tuesday blitz on chess.com (2020):

   ```
   [FEN ""]
   [Event "Titled Tuesday intern op 16th June"]
   [Site "Chess.com INT"]
   [Date "2020.06.16"]
   [Round "8"]
   [White "Sychev, Klementy"]
   [Black "Shahade, Gregory P"]
   [Result "1-0"]
   [ECO "D82"]
   [WhiteElo "2572"]
   [BlackElo "2476"]
   [StartPly "114"]

   1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 d5 4. Bf4 Bg7 5. Qa4+ Bd7 6. Qb3 dxc4 7. Qxb7 Bc6 8.
   Qxc7 Qxc7 9. Bxc7 O-O 10. Nf3 Nbd7 11. e3 Rfc8 12. Bg3 Nh5 13. Be2 Nxg3 14.
   hxg3 Rab8 15. O-O-O e6 16. Ne1 Nb6 17. Bf3 Bxf3 18. Nxf3 Bf8 19. Kc2 Nd5 20.
   Nxd5 exd5 21. Rb1 Rb7 22. Rhc1 a5 23. Ng1 a4 24. Ne2 Bb4 25. Kd1 Rcb8 26. Rc2
   Kf8 27. Nf4 Rb5 28. Ne2 Ke7 29. g4 Kd6 30. g5 Ba5 31. a3 Bd8 32. f4 Be7 33. Nc3
   Ra5 34. Rf2 Kc6 35. Kc2 Ra7 36. g4 Ra5 37. Rh2 Ra7 38. Rxh7 Rab7 39. Rxf7 Kd6
   40. Rg7 Ke6 41. Rxg6+ Kf7 42. Ra6 Rh8 43. Nxd5 Rh2+ 44. Kc3 Rb3+ 45. Kxc4 Rc2+
   46. Nc3 Rcxc3+ 47. bxc3 Rxb1 48. Rxa4 Re1 49. Kd3 Rd1+ 50. Ke4 Rg1 51. Kf5 Rc1
   52. Rc4 Rb1 53. g6+ Kf8 54. e4 Rb6 55. e5 Kg7 56. Rc7 Kf8 57. g7+ Kf7 58. Rxe7+
   Kg8 59. Re8+ Kxg7 60. Re7+ Kg8 61. Rd7 Kf8 62. d5 Ke8 63. Ra7 Kf8 64. d6 Ke8
   65. Ke6 Kf8 66. f5 Rb7 67. Ra8+ Kg7 68. Rd8 Kh6 69. f6 Rh7 70. f7 Kg5 71. Rg8+
   Kf4 72. f8=Q+ Ke4 73. Qf5+ Ke3 74. Qxh7 Kd2 75. c4 Kc3 76. c5 Kd4 77. c6 Kc5
   78. c7 Kb6 79. c8=Q Kb5 80. g5 Ka4 81. Qhc7 Kb3 82. Q7b7+ Ka2 83. d7 Ka1 84.
   d8=Q Ka2 85. Rh8 Ka1 86. g6 Ka2 87. g7 Ka1 88. Kf6 Ka2 89. e6 Ka1 90. e7 Ka2
   91. e8=Q Ka1 92. Rh1+ Ka2 93. g8=Q+ Kxa3 94. Qbb3# 1-0
   ```
3. [Alavi Moghaddam, Sayed Javad](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/12500607) vs. [Omariev, Maksim](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/4193423) at a Titled Tuesday blitz on chess.com (2021):

   ```
   [FEN ""]
   [Event "Titled Tuesday intern op 06th July"]
   [Site "Chess.com INT"]
   [Date "2021.07.06"]
   [Round "2"]
   [White "Alavi Moghaddam, Sayed Javad"]
   [Black "Omariev, Maksim"]
   [Result "1-0"]
   [ECO "B22"]
   [WhiteElo "2445"]
   [BlackElo "2304"]
   [StartPly "78"]

   1. e4 c5 2. c3 Nf6 3. e5 Nd5 4. d4 cxd4 5. cxd4 e6 6. Nf3 b6 7. Bc4 Bb7 8. O-O
   Be7 9. Bxd5 Bxd5 10. Nc3 Bxf3 11. Qxf3 Nc6 12. Qg3 Nxd4 13. Qxg7 Rf8 14. Qxh7
   Nf5 15. Nd5 d6 16. Nxe7 Qxe7 17. exd6 Qf6 18. Qh5 Rh8 19. Qf3 Rd8 20. Rd1 Kf8
   21. Bf4 Nh4 22. Qe3 Nf5 23. Qe5 Qxe5 24. Bxe5 Rh6 25. Rac1 f6 26. Bf4 e5 27.
   Bxh6+ Nxh6 28. d7 Ke7 29. Rc8 Nf7 30. Rxd8 Kxd8 31. h4 Ke7 32. h5 Kd8 33. g4 e4
   34. Kg2 Ne5 35. h6 Nf7 36. h7 b5 37. b4 a6 38. a3 f5 39. gxf5 e3 40. fxe3 Nh8
   41. e4 Nf7 42. e5 Nh8 43. e6 Nf7 44. exf7 a5 45. bxa5 Kc7 46. d8=Q+ Kc6 47.
   f8=Q b4 48. axb4 Kb5 49. h8=Q Ka6 50. Qfe7 Kb5 51. f6 Ka4 52. f7 Kb3 53. f8=Q
   Ka2 54. b5 Kb3 55. b6 Ka4 56. a6 Kb5 57. a7 Kc6 58. a8=Q+ Kb5 59. b7 Kc4 60.
   Qhg7 Kb3 61. b8=Q+ Kc2 62. Qbc8+ Kb3 63. Qab8+ Ka2 64. Qff7# 1-0
   ```

Some more serious (and fascinating) ones:

1. [Li, Di](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/8607508) vs. [Xu, Xiangyu](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/8608288) at the Chinese National Rapid Championship (2017):

   ```
   [FEN ""]
   [Event "CHN-ch rapid"]
   [Site "Shenzhen"]
   [Date "2017.12.07"]
   [Round "4"]
   [White "Li, Di"]
   [Black "Xu, Xiangyu"]
   [Result "1/2-1/2"]
   [ECO "D44"]
   [WhiteElo "2485"]
   [BlackElo "2549"]
   [StartPly "58"]

   1. d4 d5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. c4 e6 4. Nc3 c6 5. Bg5 dxc4 6. e4 b5 7. e5 h6 8. Bh4 g5
   9. Nxg5 hxg5 10. Bxg5 Nbd7 11. g3 Bb7 12. Bg2 Qb6 13. exf6 c5 14. d5 O-O-O 15.
   O-O b4 16. Na4 Qb5 17. a3 exd5 18. axb4 cxb4 19. Be3 Nc5 20. Qg4+ Rd7 21. Nxc5
   Bxc5 22. Bxc5 Qxc5 23. Rfe1 Kc7 24. Re5 Rhd8 25. h4 Bc6 26. h5 a5 27. h6 a4 28.
   h7 a3 29. bxa3 b3 30. Rae1 b2 31. Qe2 c3 32. Re8 Rxe8 33. Qxe8 c2 34. Qe5+ Rd6
   35. Qe7+ Bd7 36. h8=Q b1=Q 37. Bf1 Kb7 38. Qh6 Qd1 39. Qhf8 Qdd4 40. Re3 c1=Q
   41. Rb3+ Qb6 42. Rxb6+ Qxb6 43. Qxd6 Qxf1+ 44. Kxf1 Qb1+ 45. Kg2 Qe4+ 46. Kh2
   Qh7+ 1/2-1/2
   ```
2. [Arnaudov, Petar G](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/2907127) vs. Moser, Eva at the 4th Augsburg Gutmann Memorial (2013):

   ```
   [FEN ""]
   [Event "Augsburg Gutmann Memorial 4th"]
   [Site "Augsburg"]
   [Date "2013.12.31"]
   [Round "5"]
   [White "Arnaudov, Petar G"]
   [Black "Moser, Eva"]
   [Result "0-1"]
   [ECO "A80"]
   [WhiteElo "2442"]
   [BlackElo "2436"]
   [StartPly "54"]

   1. d4 f5 2. Bg5 h6 3. Bh4 g5 4. e3 Nf6 5. Bg3 d6 6. h4 g4 7. Bd3 Nc6 8. Ne2 e5
   9. Bb5 Qe7 10. c4 Bd7 11. Nbc3 Bg7 12. d5 Nd8 13. Bxd7+ Qxd7 14. Qc2 O-O 15. e4
   f4 16. Bh2 Nh5 17. O-O-O Nf7 18. f3 g3 19. Bg1 Qe7 20. Kb1 Bf6 21. Nc1 Nh8 22.
   b4 Ng6 23. c5 Nxh4 24. Nb3 b6 25. Rc1 Ng7 26. Nb5 h5 27. a4 Qd7 28. Qe2 Rfc8
   29. a5 bxc5 30. bxc5 a6 31. c6 Qe7 32. Na7 Rcb8 33. Ka2 Rb4 34. Rxh4 Bxh4 35.
   Rc4 Rbb8 36. Ra4 Bf6 37. Qxa6 h4 38. Qb7 Qf7 39. a6 h3 40. gxh3 Qh5 41. Nb5 Ne8
   42. Nxc7 Nxc7 43. Qxc7 Qxf3 44. Bb6 Qg2+ 45. Ka3 Qxh3 46. a7 Re8 47. Qb7 f3 48.
   Bc7 f2 49. Bb8 f1=Q 50. Qxa8 g2 51. Qb7 g1=Q 52. a8=Q Qc5+ 53. Qb4 Qa1# 0-1
   ```
3. [Belov, Igor](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/4101782) vs. [Prohorov, Vladimir](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/909025) (1991 - the oldest I found):

   ```
   [FEN ""]
   [Event "Cheliabinsk op"]
   [Site "Cheliabinsk"]
   [Date "1991"]
   [Round "?"]
   [White "Belov, Igor"]
   [Black "Prohorov, Vladimir"]
   [Result "0-1"]
   [ECO "E97"]
   [WhiteElo "2440"]
   [BlackElo "2230"]
   [PlyCount "164"]
   [StartPly "56"]

   1. Nf3 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. d4 O-O 6. Be2 e5 7. O-O Nc6 8. d5
   Ne7 9. Bg5 h6 10. Bxf6 Bxf6 11. b4 Bg7 12. c5 f5 13. Nd2 Kh7 14. Rc1 Ng8 15.
   cxd6 cxd6 16. Nb5 Nf6 17. Nc7 Rb8 18. Bd3 f4 19. Qa4 a6 20. b5 Nh5 21. f3 Rf7
   22. b6 Bf8 23. Qb3 Ng7 24. Rc2 Qf6 25. Rfc1 Bd7 26. Bxa6 bxa6 27. Nxa6 Rb7 28.
   Rc7 Qg5 29. h4 Rxc7 30. Nxc7 Qxh4 31. b7 Nh5 32. b8=Q Ng3 33. Qc4 Qh1+ 34. Kf2
   Qh4 35. Kg1 Qh1+ 36. Kf2 Qh4 37. Kg1 Qh1+ 38. Kf2 Qh4 39. Qb6 Be7 40. Nf1 Qh1
   41. Nd2 Qh4 42. Ke1 Qh1+ 43. Nf1 Bh4 44. Kd2 Qxg2+ 45. Kc3 Ne2+ 46. Kb2 Nxc1+
   47. Kxc1 Qxf3 48. Ne6 Qa3+ 49. Kd2 Be7 50. Qcb3 Qa8 51. Qc7 Be8 52. a3 Qa6 53.
   Qcc4 Qa7 54. Qf3 Bh4 55. Qh3 g5 56. Nd8 Bd7 57. Qhc3 Rg7 58. Nc6 Qg1 59. Kc2 g4
   60. Nb8 Be8 61. Nd2 Bg6 62. Qc8 Qg2 63. Nd7 Be7 64. Nxe5 dxe5 65. Qxe5 Bxa3 66.
   Qcc3 Bf8 67. d6 f3 68. d7 f2 69. d8=Q f1=Q 70. Qde7 Qf7 71. Qxf7 Bxf7 72. Qf5+
   Kg8 73. Qfc8 Qf2 74. Qb4 Bg6 75. Qbc4+ Kh7 76. Qxg4 Bd6 77. Qce6 Bb4 78. Qd5
   Rc7+ 79. Kd1 Bxd2 80. Qxd2 Qf1+ 81. Qe1 Rc1+ 82. Kxc1 Qxe1+ 0-1
   ```
4. [Mackic, Zoran](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/915602) vs. [Maksimenko, Andrei](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/14100584) (1994 - pretty old as well):

   ```
   [FEN ""]
   [Event "YUG-chT2"]
   [Site "Yugoslavia"]
   [Date "1994"]
   [Round "5"]
   [White "Mackic, Zoran"]
   [Black "Maksimenko, Andrei"]
   [Result "0-1"]
   [ECO "B96"]
   [WhiteElo "2400"]
   [BlackElo "2430"]
   [StartPly "68"]

   1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 a6 6. Bg5 e6 7. f4 Nc6 8. Nxc6
   bxc6 9. e5 h6 10. Bh4 g5 11. fxg5 Nd5 12. Nxd5 cxd5 13. Qh5 Qb6 14. Be2 Bg7 15.
   g6 O-O 16. Bf6 Ra7 17. Bxg7 Kxg7 18. gxf7 Raxf7 19. Qg4+ Kh8 20. O-O-O Qe3+ 21.
   Kb1 dxe5 22. Rhe1 Rg7 23. Qb4 Qf4 24. Qd6 e4 25. Qa3 Rxg2 26. Bxa6 Bxa6 27.
   Qxa6 Qe5 28. Rf1 Rb8 29. Qa3 e3 30. Rf8+ Rxf8 31. Qxf8+ Kh7 32. Qf7+ Rg7 33.
   Qf3 d4 34. a4 Qf5 35. Qe2 e5 36. a5 Qf2 37. Qd3+ Kh8 38. Qe4 Qxh2 39. a6 Qf4
   40. Qh1 Kh7 41. Rf1 Qg4 42. Qd5 e4 43. Qa5 d3 44. a7 d2 45. a8=Q e2 46. Rf6
   d1=Q+ 47. Ka2 e1=Q 48. Rxh6+ Kxh6 49. Qh8+ Kg6 50. Qa6+ Kf7 51. Qb7+ Qdd7 0-1
   ```

Reference (from the CQL documentation):

- [`sort`](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/sort.html)
- [`#`](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/hash.html)
- [`Q`, `q` designators](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/piecedesignator.html#piecetype)

Download CQL for Windows and Mac along with some examples [from the official website](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/download.html). Email the authors for the Linux distribution.